# Check the text in html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html dir = rtl>
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="ar">
        <script type="javascript">
        function d()
            {               
                document.getElementById("sName").innerHTML ='Name submitted';
            }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form name = "Info" method = "set" action = "">
           <table  border = "0" width = "40%" align = "center">
           <tr>
                   <td> الاســــــــــــــــم: </td>
                   <td> <input type="text" name = "CurName" size = "31"> </td>
                   <td> <p id = "sName"> </p> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td> العــــــــــــــــمر :</td>
                   <td> <input type = "text" name = "CurAddress" size = "10"></td>
           <td> <p id = "sAddress"> </p> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td> العنـــــــــــــوان :</td>
                   <td> <input type = "text" name = "CurAddress" size = "45"></td>
           <td> <p id = "sAddress"> </p> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td> الحالــــــــــــــــة :</td>
                   <td> <input type = "radio" name = "Mar" > متزوج<input type = "radio" name = "Sin" > أعزب</td>
           <td> <p id = "SitName"> </p> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>                   
                  <td colspan = 2 align = center> <button type = "submit" onClick = "d(); return false;">ارسال </button>  <button type = "reset">مسح</button> </td>                 
               </tr>
          </table>
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I press the submit button I expected that some words beside the first textbox will disappear, but nothing happened. Can some one explain to me where the problem is?

Comment: Note that you have two paragraphs with the same id (`sAddress`).  id's should be unique.

Comment: Where is your code to disappear  some words :)

Comment: @santanukumar document.getElementById("sName").innerHTML ='Name submitted';

Comment: That is for displaying Name submitted if you have a unique id sName.Where is the code for disappear some words :)

Comment: What do you mean @santanukumar

Comment: @Anish Gupta i mean where did he tried to disappear some words.There are syntax errors i agree.. He didn't say for appear but for disappear..What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and change

```
<button type = "submit" onClick = "d();">
```

to

```
<button type = "button" onClick = "d();">
```

or else your page gonna be reloading

Answer (score 3):

You have not properly defined your `script` tag. Proper value will be `text/javascript`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

instead of

```
<script type="javascript">
```

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian now you know :)

Answer (score 2):

Your js code is correct but you have to change that

```
  <script type="javascript"> as <script type="text/javascript">
```

See your code here its working perfectly in jsfiddle

```
      http://jsfiddle.net/WxtJ3/
```